# Buffer size for ssh session in paramiko-expect

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am using paramiko-expect to send commands to a server. It is working as expected except when there is pagination options in the returned prompt.
In that case, the output text is missing the first character in the output of each new page command and sometimes hangs. Putting buffer_size=1 is the only thing that fixes it for me.

That solution is too slow though, is there anything else I can do?

```
    interact = SSHClientInteraction(ssh, timeout=300, display=True, buffer_size=1)  
    output = ''
    command = "file search activelog /platform/log/certm.log INFO"
    not_done = True
    interact.send(command)
    while not_done:
        interact_index = interact.expect(['.*Press <enter> for 1 line, <space> for one page, or <q> to quit', '.*Search completed'], timeout=300)
        output += interact.current_output_clean
        if interact_index == 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            interact.send(' ')
        else:
            not_done = False
    print(output)

    ssh.close()
```